# How widely Master/Visa credit/debit cards are accepted in Slovenia (Julian Alps)?

Tags: payment-cards, slovenia

How widely accepted are credit and debit cards (Mastercard/VISA networks) in Slovenia? My principle area of interest are in and around the Julian Alps (Bled/Bovec/Trianon etc). Are there different levels of acceptance between:

1. Tourist focussed companies (eg Tour/activity operators)
2. Chain stores/supermarkets
3. Independent bars/restraunts
4. Small local stores

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As a Slovene/Slovenian, I can confirm that credit card coverage is quite good. You may find small local stores that only deal with cash, perhaps more frequently in remote areas, but that just means you got lucky.

Even if you find yourself in need of cash, it shouldn't be a problem finding an ATM machine. You can find them [here](http://www.bankomati.net/Bankomati.asp?0901). The page lists location, operational state of the ATM as well as acceptance of Visa/MasterCard/Diners Club cards.

MasterCard has an [online database](https://www.mastercard.us/en-us/consumers/features-benefits/contactless/contactless-locator.html) that enables searching for merchants that support their contactless payment implementation. Select `Slovenia` and enter one of the postal zip codes [found here](https://sl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seznam_po%C5%A1tnih_%C5%A1tevilk_v_Sloveniji). Note that not all merchants support contactless payments, but may still support MasterCard, so you should take that into account when checking the results, but you could get a general idea about MasterCard coverage.

Contactless has been on the rise here for the last two or so years, since our banks decided it is the next big thing and started replacing our debit cards with ones that support the technology.

Comment: A thing to remember: always take a receipt at least to the entrance of the establishment where you are buying. Though highly unlikely, you may get fined otherwise. Taking a receipt is required by law around here.

Comment: The ATM map is helpful - although apprently there really aren't that many ATMs in Slovenia (I suppose there also aren't that many people). With regard to your comment - on the spot fines seem to be a big thing in Slovenia, keep seeing warnings about them.

Comment: Yes. The warning is also required by law...

Answer (score 7):

My colleague is Slovenian (last visited there last year) and said that VISA, MasterCard, and American Express are widely accepted. The country is generally "chip" but if you don't have a chipped card, you can usually swipe it and sign. Many places and some cards issued locally accept Apple Pay.

Comment: All my cards are chip&pin, so I didn't anticipate any problems there.

Answer (score 6):

We were there last summer and used credit-cards, both Mastercard and VISA, just about everywhere, even small shops around Bled. It seems like both these cards were widely used and it's also common to accept credit-cards even in relatively small shops.

Answer (score 3):

Very high level of acceptance at 1 through 3, on a visit 8 years ago. Must be even higher today. All hotels, restaurants, and tourist attractions we visited accepted Visa. Can't speak to tiny shops, but Slovenia is a *very* connected country. Our hotel had fast wifi and large digital TVs with cable.

Comment: Is it implied in this answer that acceptance in 4. is patchy, or did you just never try to buy from a corner shop in the mountains?

Comment: Don't recall doing business with any small retailer. This is so long ago (10 years, now that I Iook it up) that Slovenia had not yet adopted the euro. By now, use of plastic there must be universal.